# AddDynamic function Not working in unreal engine

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unreal-engine4

The 'AddDynamic' function for unreal engine 4.27.2 is not showing. I am trying to reference the 'onBeginOverlap' function with the script. And for some reason it shows an error. Could someone please help me? here is my code.

```
void ABatteryManController::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();

    GetCapsuleComponent()->OnComponentBeginOverlap.AddDynamic(this, & ABatteryManController::onBeginOverlap);
    
}

void ABatteryManController::onBeginOverlap(UPrimitiveComponent* HitComp,
    AActor* otherActor, UprimitiveComponent* otherComp, int32 OtherBodyIndex, bool 
    bFromSweep, const FHitResult& SweepResult)
{

    if (otherActor->ActorHasTag("Recharge")) {
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Collided With"));
    }
```

And here is my Header code for said thing

```
UFUNCTION()
    void onBeginOverlap(class UPrimitiveComponent* HitComp, class AActor* otherActor, class UprimitiveComponent* otherComp, int32 OtherBodyIndex, bool bFromSweep, const FHitResult& SweepResult);
```

Comment: Which error are you getting?

Comment: In some instances, `UPrimitiveComponent` is spelled with a lowercase `p`.

Comment: Okay so the error i am getting is Error E0304 
@goose_lake

Comment: @Rotem I tried lowercasing it and it gave me another error

Comment: It would be helpful to post the exact errors you're getting, it's difficult to help when you don't provide information. And you weren't supposed to use a lowercase `p`. The class name is `UPrimitiveComponent`

Comment: @Rotem

E0304 no instance of function template "FComponenetBeginOverlapSignature::_Internal_AddDynamic" matches the argument list

Comment: Assuming it's spelled correctly now, did you include the header for PrimitiveComponent? And also that is not the complete error, the rest will tell you what the expected signature is and what the signature you're giving it is.